# How to check if the value from the json Data is null

Tags: jquery, json

below is the json data. What I want to do Is, I want to check if the data is empty then, the No Records text will be shown. Below is my code. However I always get the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'detailedInfo' of undefined at line `.detailedInfo[0]!=null` How can I fix that?

```
 {
        "status": "0",
        "message": "",
        "objectList": [{
            "customerID": "A112",
            "dateReg": "31/08/2015",
            "detailedInfo": [{
                "purchDate": "01/08/2015",
                "prodCode": null,
                "price": null,
                "catefory": "BF"
            }],
            "subTotal": 23.00
        }],
        "objectList2": null
    }

if(data.objectList[0].detailedInfo[0]!=null){
    for(var i=0;i<data.objectList[0].detailedInfo.length;i++){
           var purchaseDt = data.objectList[0].detailedInfo[i].purchDate;
           var productCd = data.objectList[0].detailedInfo[i].prodCode;
           var category = data.objectList[0].detailedInfo[i].myrEquiv;

           $('#Date').append(purchaseDt);
           $('#Code').append(productCd);
           $('#Category').append(category);
    }
}
else{
     $('#noDataMsg').text("There is no record found");
     $('#noDataMsg').show();
}
```

Comment: the only i had is `infoData` is not defined in `var category = infoData[0].detailedInfo[i].myrEquiv;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ub0oug4x/

Comment: whenever you try to access an element of an array at some index position then before accessing that element just check whether that array is defined and not null and length of the array is less than or eqal to the index position. so add this line `if(data.objectList[0].detailedInfo)` before the line you mentioned in OP. the same thing also applies to `data.objectList[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because `data.objectList` is an empty array `[]`, so trying to access anything in offset zero, like `data.objectList[0]` is `undefined`, and hence you cannot access `detailedInfo` of `undefined`.

Why don't you simply test that the objectList exist and that it has a length greater than zero, like this;

```
if(data.objectList && data.objectList.length > 0){
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

The above should do it, unless you need to handle corner cases such as objectList suddenly being a string instead of an Array -- depending on your requirements, you may add a test to the if-statement of the `typeof != 'string'` to handle that case as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check your data because data.objectList[0] does not have a detailedInfo property set.